# Uninstall apps installed from their APK

Tags: apk, uninstallation

I'm developing a game from Unity for Android, I created the first version, uploaded the APK to the phone, tap it, installed, nice.

Now I have a new build, if I do the same, it won't install because the app is already installed.

How do I completely remove the app? If I long press and drop into the bin, it does nothing. The app does not appear under "My Apps" in Google Play Store.

Using Android 4.1.2 and Samsung Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't be shown in Google Play Store because you have not uploaded it to the store. To uninstall the app go to

Settings -> Apps -> *find your app* -> Uninstall

Comment: Also, if you have root access, you can manually delete it from terminal. Or you ca use command `adb uninstall <package_name>` to uninstall a package. Guide to use adb shell to uninstall package: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18756111/3127685

Comment: where should it be installed? I did not find it